# Cannot return IObservable<T> from a method marked async

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

This contrived example is roughly how my code is structured:

```
public abstract class SuperHeroBase
{
    protected SuperHeroBase() { }

    public async Task<CrimeFightingResult> FightCrimeAsync()
    {
        var result = new CrimeFightingResult();

        result.State = CrimeFightingStates.Fighting;

        try
        {
            await FightCrimeOverride(results);
        } 
        catch
        {
            SetError(results);
        }

        if (result.State == CrimeFightingStates.Fighting)
            result.State = CrimeFightingStates.GoodGuyWon;

        return result;
    }

    protected SetError(CrimeFightingResult results)
    {
        result.State = CrimeFightingStates.BadGuyWon;
    }

    protected abstract Task FightCrimeOverride(CrimeFightingResult results);
}

public enum CrimeFightingStates
{
    NotStarted,
    Fighting,
    GoodGuyWon, // success state
    BadGuyWon // error state
}

public class CrimeFightingResult
{
    internal class CrimeFightingResult() { }

    public CrimeFightingStates State { get; internal set; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to build a collection that would hold multiple SuperHero objects and offer a `AllHerosFightCrime` method. The hero's should not all fight at once (the next one starts when the first is finished).

```
public class SuperHeroCollection : ObservableCollection<SuperHeroBase>
{
    public SuperHeroCollection() { }

    // I mark the method async...
    public async IObservable<CrimeFightingResult> AllHerosFightCrime()
    {
        var heros = new List<SuperHeroBase>(this);

        var results = new ReplaySubject<CrimeFightingResult>();

        foreach (var hero in heros)
        {
            // ... so I can await on FightCrimeAsync and push 
            // the result to the subject when done
            var result = await hero.FightCrimeAsync();
            results.OnNext(result);
        }

        results.OnCompleted();

        // I can't return the IObservable here because the method is marked Async.
        // It expects a return type of CrimeFightingResult
        return results;
    }
}
```

How can I return the `IObservable<CrimeFightingResults>` and still have the call to `FightCrimeAsync` awaited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could turn your task into an observable and combine them using `Merge`:

```
public IObservable<CrimeFightingResult> AllHerosFightCrime()
{
    var heros = new List<SuperHeroBase>(this);
    return heros.Select(h => h.FightCrimeAsync().ToObservable())
        .Merge();
}
```

If you want to maintain the order your events are received you can use `Concat` instead of `Merge`.

Comment: By what you've written, I think the second `FightCrimeAsync` is allowed to be started before the first has finished. Even if the current implementations of `Select`, `ToObservable` and `Merge` make this behave the way you want, the description of those functions allow other behaviour.

Comment: After running some more detailed tests with this code, @hvd is correct. The FightCrimeAsync tasks can run out of sequence.

Comment: @mbursill - If you want to keep the order, use `Concat` instead of `Merge`.

Comment: You probably need a Defer if you want to do that: ".Select(h => Observable.Defer(() => async h.FightCrimeAsync()))"